# Unable to create directory '{p}'. Unable to verify the directory exists: '{testDir}'

Tags: build, devops, pipeline

Publishing build artifacts failed with an error: Unable to create directory '{p}'. Unable to verify the directory exists: '{testDir}'. If directory is a file share, please verify the share name is correct, the share is online, and the current process has permission to access the share

I have similar pipeline and that is working fine but this one is not working

Comment: What CI do you use? Please add this to the tags